# Print out the numbers among 1 and 200 that can be divisible by 13

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement, do-while

```
    int i=1;
    do
    {
        if (i % 13 == 0)
            Response.Write(i + "<br>");

        i++;
    } while (i < 201);
```

as title, I want to print out the numbers that can be divisible by 13 from 1 to 200
The code above works, but why can't I write it this way?

```
    int i=1;
    do
    {
        Response.Write(i + "<br>");

        i++;
    } while (i < 201 && i % 13 = 0);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because as soon as your first `i` is not divisible by `13`, your `do-while` loop ends.

Comment: you could just do `for(int i=13; i<201; i+=13) Response.Write(i + "<br>");` instead.  Basically the powers of 13.

Comment: @juharr Multiples of 13, not powers of 13.

Comment: @Servy yes, it's been a long week

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two loops are not the same. One of them continues as long as `i < 201`.Other one stops at the first number that can't be divided to 13.

Answer (score 1):

In the second version, your while loop is using i % 13 == 0 as a part of the test for whether the while loop should even continue.  So as soon as a number is not divisible by 13, the loop will stop.

The key here is that there are two different tests:
 - the loop should continue as long as the number is not over 200
 - a particular number should be printed if it is divisible by 13

So no arrangement that combines these into one test will be able to achieve the goal.